# how to select a cell that matches another cell value vba

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how i might select any cell in a range that matches another?
for Example:

comparing range ("A9:A200") to range("B9")

if say range ("A10") is "bellingham" and range ("B9") is also bellingham

I want A10 to be the active cell.

any help would be most apreciated. thank you.

Comment: The Range object has a `Find()` method which you can use to match a value.

Comment: For Each cell In Range("A9:A210")
If cell.Value = Range("b10").Value Then
cell.Select
End If

Next
End Sub

Comment: Im making a barcode scanner check in/check out sheet for tools at work. I have it made. but a co worker came up with an idea to make checkin easier. which is essentially when A9 equals checkin and b9 equals a value in range A10:A200 on. to select that cell. for sake of argument it will be A10 then i will active cell offset and autofill the time and technician who signed it in. im new to vba and literally started yesterday. i have been googling like a mad man but i figured it might be easier to post the question for this.

Comment: probably a duplicate question of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35225453/5821186)

Comment: You can edit your original question and add the new information from your comments into the question

Comment: Do you want it to be the activecell or do you want to do something with the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in the sheet code module for the worksheet holding your data:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, f As Range, v
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B9"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        v = Trim(rng.Value)

        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            Set f = Me.Range("A10:A500").Find(what:=rng.Value, _
                                              lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not f Is Nothing Then
                If Me.Range("A9").Value = "checkin" Then
                    f.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
                    f.Offset(0, 2).Value = "userName" 'from where?
                    f.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Checked In" 
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Scanned value '" & rng.Value & "' not found !", _
                        vbExclamation
            End If 'found a match

        End If 'cell has a value

    End If 'checking this value

End Sub
```

Adjust ranges to suit...

Comment: thanks Tim i will give your suggestion a shot tomorrow when i head in for work. currently my spreadsheet is at work and was merely trying to get a game plan for tomorrow. sorry i wasn't very detailed with my initial question. if it doesn't work i will bring it home and be much more specific and detailed with my question so that the community can assist. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Might it be easier to use a formula like match to do it?  If you want to call it from VBA you could use worksheetfunction.match.